# Redirect Loop on Magento Subdomain hosted on Apache Server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite

I am pulling my hair out trying to figure out why we suddenly get a redirect loop on our subdomain taymarplasticdisplays.com
It was working perfectly up until a week ago, with no changes being made on our end.  I call Godaddy and they tell me to check the .htaccess file for errors, but I can't figure out where the disconnect is!  Here is what the current Rewrite looks like:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^taymarplasticdisplays\.com$ [OR] 
 RewriteCond % {HTTP_HOST} ^www\.taymarplasticdisplays\.com$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/taymarplasticdisplays\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting **www.example.com** or **example.com** to **example.com** .The redirect loop happens when **example.com** redirects back to **example.com** (indentical destination).

just remove your first condition and you will be fine

```
 RewriteCond % {HTTP_HOST} ^www\.taymarplasticdisplays\.com$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/taymarplasticdisplays\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```